# How to fix Gnome-shell 42.9 intermittentlyl uses 100% cpu and freezes, ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome-shell

Gnome shell version 42.9 (latest) intermittently (every 2-8 Hrs) freezes all windows. Mouse ok. Using ctrl f3, TOP shows 100% cpu in one core. Other processes keep running ok.  Only a browser application running along with plasma monitor in my window. strace  seems to show some kind of FUTEX hang. I need to kill -9 Gnome   to get  screen access back. No change if a different browser used or monitor stopped. Latest 22.04 Ubuntu (SEP 2023 LAST UPDATE). Problem has existed for  many months. How do I fix this?
Suggested "related" links provided by askuobuntu at the bottom of this page have been tried, but do not fix the problem.